# git diff local vs remote feature branch

Tags: git, github, git-diff

My local feature branch, named pencils, is ahead by 3 commits. I want to do a diff with remote, also named pencil. How might I do this successfully?

The following failed

```
git fetch origin pencil:pencil
```

It failed with error: "refusing to fetch into current branch... of non-bare repository."

Comment: This is why I like to use `git fetch`, not `git pull`. Just run `git fetch` to have your Git get everything from the other Git over at `origin`. Now you have everything! Now you can easily run `git diff` or `git log` or whatever you like, to see what's been going on over at `origin`. Your only mistake here is trying to do too much at once, adding `origin pencil:pencil`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *diff* your local branch vs the remote branch, do a normal fetch (updates your tracking-branch) and then diff it:

```
git fetch
git diff pencils origin/pencils
```

This will show what changed from `pencils` to the remote `pencils` branch (assuming the default remote name of `origin` given in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Branch off from pencil and push the new branch to the server, then on the server pull from the new remote to remote pencil but don't submit the merge and just view the diff?

Another option is to diff your local pencil with HEAD~3 (means "current pencil" vs "current pencil minus 3 commits")